# How to pause and resume an Ad unit from serving Ads through Admob Network, IF POSSIBLE?

Tags: android, admob

I have a Banner Ad unit which is served only through one ad source i.e. Admob Network. I was trying to have control over it to display ad or not as per my requirement, specifically to pause or enable an Ad unit similar to what one can do with House Ad campaigns but i couldn't find anything without people suggesting me to have server controlled flag on the Ad

I even found a way around it by setting location to the Ad for a different country when i don't want to show the ad: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/targeting#location
but problem is still the same,to have control i need to make a server call to set location to my country to stat displaying the ad

Is there a solution to this? or any better one will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just add a custom empty house ad with 100% impression target? So, you won't show any real ads and also won't earn any money..?

Answer (score 1):

When You dont want to show ad,  make the Visibility of banner view to Gone

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="Your Id"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

in main activity

```
AdView  admobBannerView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

 //when ever you dont want to display ad

  admobBannerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 //when you want to display ad

 admobBannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I am looking  for solution through admob dashboard or something like that this is client end change i won't be able to switch whenever i want without an app release

Comment: may be you can do this then  http://imgur.com/a/gvCso   , in frequency capping set  1 impression for 10 days that way user can only see 1 ad  in 10 days , its almost like disabling ads

Comment: You can't set frequency capping for a Banner Ad, only Interstitial Ads have the option

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and thinking to create a DB table on a remote server with a flag to enable/disable ad serving. The implementation seems quite simple. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025839/flutter-dart-download-data-from-mysql-server-database