# Flutter/dart- download data from mysql server database

Tags: dart, flutter

To preface this i am new to all of this and don't need step by step information, just seeing what is possible.

I've been toying around with connecting my flutter/dart app to a mysql backend

Im connecting to it using sqljocky and was wondering if there is anyway users can download data from it for offline use. I read about NSUserDefaults (for ios) and Shared_Preferences (for android) for storage of persistent and simple data on the app and wanted to know if this is the correct route to continue on.

Comment: Use SQLite equivalent [SQFlite](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite)

Answer (score 7):

I think this answer is required here:

Few days ago I had to dealt with a existing MySQL database and there was no way to do it with Dart except over network requests(there is a sqljocky package which is Dart 2 incompatible). Read best options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415178/flutter-connecting-to-a-database-in-server/49415621#49415621).

Here Im going to show an example for a simple fetch data using Flutter http request with simple PHP & MySQL.

Note: This is may not 100% secure.

If you are doing in local server, you need to have server(ex: apache) running and MySQL(you can use XAMPP to get both).

- **Step 1:** create a database.
- **Step 2:** create a folder in htdocs(in XAMP). Next, inside that file create file called conn.php. Then, add below snippet and change
  with your db credentials to connect to database.

  ```
  <?php

      $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "db_name");

      if (!$connection) {
          echo "connection failed!";
          exit();
      }
  ?>
  ```

Note: above snippet is a simple example and you can customize as you want.

- **Step 3:** Create php file called fetch_data.php and copy paste below code snippet:

  ```
  <?php 

    include("conn.php");

    $queryResult = $connection->
        query("SELECT * FROM your_table");//change your_table with your database table that you want to fetch values

    $result = array();

    while ($fetchdata=$queryResult->fetch_assoc()) {
        $result[] = $fetchdata;
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
   ?>
  ```

Above code snippet will fetch the data from db table and display it after `json_encode`.

**Step 4:** Open up your Flutter project or create one. Below is a code snippet that requesting for fetched data and display them using a `ListView`.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Login",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get('http://10.0.2.2/fluttertest/fetch_data.php');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        data = json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
                title: Text(data[index]['title']),
              )),
    );
  }
}
```

There is an important thing, you should keep in mind: `10.0.2.2` or your machine IP address(type `ipconfig` in cmd to get your IP address) have to use because emulator itself localhost(127.0.0.1).

Note: I didn't use any model or advanced things to show you bare minimum example. If you want a great CRUD example, check [my github repo](https://github.com/blasanka/flutter_mysql) and you can also do some pull requests because it's can extended.

If you want to insert or update data, you can use `http.post()` and in php use `INSERT`, `UPDATE` sql statements(It's better using Prepared Statement to prevent sql injections).

Also you can read my article. There I have explained everything using a CRUD application.

Answer (score 4):

For Android we can use SQLite and for Flutter, we have equivalent [SQFlite](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite) that support both IOS and Android.

And there are other best solutions like [Firebase database, Firestore](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/FlutterFire.md) and you can also create API and access through HTTP. Also you can store data in a JSON file.

For you to continue on these may help:

[Using mysql in flutter.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16068)

[Flutter connecting to a database in server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415178/flutter-connecting-to-a-database-in-server)